# Uniqueness of maxima of product of convex and linear functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to maximize a function of the form
$f(x) = xg(x)$, where $g(x)$ is decreasing in $x$, is convex in $x$ and $g(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I can show that $0<|g'(0)|<\infty$, which indicates that $f(x)$ has at least one local maximum.

I want to figure out what additional conditions on $g(x)$ are necessary in order for there to exist at most one local maximum, i.e., in order for there to be a single global maximum for $f(x)$.

More specifically, $g(x) = \int_0^\infty h(y) e^{-x k(y)} {\mathrm d}y$, for some functions $h$ and $k$.

I'd appreciate any pointers/ideas!

Comment: Your assumptions seem to be contradictory. If $g$ is convex, $g'$ is increasing. Together with $g'(0) > 0$ this contradicts $g(x) \to 0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to write $|g'(0)|$ instead of $g'(0)$. I've edited the question!